# How do you search for pfUsers on a parseBased iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, uitableview

Im currently making an app that involves searching and adding friends but right now i'm stuck on the logic of searching and listing users on the app.

So basically if the text which was typed on the searchbar was "Beyonce", I want to match words from username column on my parse Table like:

Beyonce
Beyoncecarter
beyonceKnowls 
(supposing they exists on the app)

So far I have created a tableview in my viewcontroller:

```
- (void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar*)searchBar{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    tableView=[[UITableView alloc]init];
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,99,screenWidth,420);
    tableView.dataSource=self;
    tableView.delegate=self;
    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [tableView reloadData];
    tableView.opaque = NO;
    tableView.backgroundView  = nil;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}
```

This is how i populate the tableview but this only list one user:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    [cell setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    cell.textLabel.text = [SearchList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

This is when the user clicks the search button:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    NSString *searchResult = [searchBar.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"username" matchesRegex:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",searchResult]];
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if (object) {
            PFUser *user = (PFUser *)object;
            NSLog(@"Username: %@", user.username);
            if (SearchList.count > 0) {
                [SearchList replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:user.username];
            } else {
                [SearchList addObject:user.username];
            }
            [tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];

}
```

Someone pleaseee instruct me on what to do cause i really cant think this through, Thanks a Billion !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to show all this unrelated UI code. I'll take the intent from your question literally:

> I  want to search PFUsers that have a username containing the word "Beyonce"

Have you even **tried** looking at the [Parse iOS/OSX documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS)? It's a very user-friendly, helpful resource, and you should be able to get your information faster than asking a question on Stack Overflow.

For your sake, I **will** insert a block of code that will help you achieve this:

You'll want to use a `PFQuery` object, configure it and run it asynchronously (or synchronously with `findObjects`, but ew.) like so:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Users"];
[query whereKey:@"username" containsString:@"Beyonce"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    // No error; search succeeded.
    NSLog(@"%@", objects); // Your search results!
  } else {
    // Oh god. There was an error.
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]); // Log the error to debug.
  }
}];
```

I hoped that helped, next time use the docs!

Comment: Thanks alot ! and i also tried using the docs but got confused